# Trouble Understanding Error Related to Promises and Scope

Tags: javascript, particle.io

I am working on a little web front end for a particle photon I have configured as a learning exercise for js.

I am having an error and I can't figure out why.

Earlier in the code I use the particle script to login https://docs.particle.io/reference/javascript/#with-username-password

```
var particle = new Particle();
var token;

particle.login({username: 'user@email.com', password: 'pass'}).then(
  function(data) {
    token = data.body.access_token;
  },
  function (err) {
    console.log('Could not log in.', err);
  }
);
```

In this example I use particle.login() and then immediately use .then on it.
It works just fine and I get the token I expect.

Next I want to list all my devices, I use the example code from the documentation to do this:

```
var devicesPr = particle.listDevices({ auth: token });

devicesPr.then(
  function(devices){
    console.log('Devices: ', devices);
  },
  function(err) {
    console.log('List devices call failed: ', err);
  }
);
```

This also works perfectly. No trouble.

**Here is my problem:**

I thought to myself "gee, why don't I just get rid of this var devicesPr and just call then on it immediately". So I try:

```
particle.listDevices({auth: token}).then(
    function(devices){
        console.log('Devices: ', devices);
    },
    function(err) {
        console.log('List of devices call failed: ', err);
    }
);
```

Now I get an error saying:

```
init.js:23 List of devices call failed:  {statusCode: 400, errorDescription: "HTTP error 400 from /v1/devices - The access token was not found", error: Error: Unsuccessful HTTP response
    at Request.<anonymous> (http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particle-api-j…, body: {…}}
init.js:11 API call completed on promise resolve: API KEY
```

So what I notice is that it seems like the request for the devices list is being performed before the auth token is generated. I suppose that makes sense as a possibility, since the documentation for promises keep mentioning they are asynchronous.

I am just confused why I don't see the same possible error when I make it a variable first and then call .then on it? Does it somehow  know to wait for the auth token to exist if I store the promise to a variable first?

Thanks!

Full trouble code as I am running it:

```
"use strict";

//var Particle = require('particle-api-js');
var particle = new Particle();
var token;


particle.login({username: 'MYEMAIL', password:'MYPASSWORD'}).then(
  function(data){
    token = data.body.access_token;
    console.log('API call completed on promise resolve: ', token);
  },
  function(err) {
    console.log('API call completed on promise fail: ', err);
  }
);

particle.listDevices({auth: token}).then(
    function(devices){
        console.log('Devices: ', devices);
    },
    function(err) {
        console.log('List of devices call failed: ', err);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not chaining `listDevices` with the `token` gotten from `particle.login` - you're calling `particle.listDevices` *synchronously*, before `token` has been populated. The request to get the token may have been sent, but the asynchronous `.then` that populated `token` surely hasn't run yet.

Instead, use `.then` to chain `listDevices` after the `particle.login`, like this:

```
var particle = new Particle();
particle.login({username: 'MYEMAIL', password:'MYPASSWORD'})
  .then(data => {
    const token = data.body.access_token;
    console.log('API call completed on promise resolve: ', token);
    // Return the listDevices promise so `.then` can be called on it below:
    return particle.listDevices({auth: token});
  })
  .catch(err => console.log('API call completed on promise fail: ', err))
  .then(devices => console.log('Devices: ', devices))
  .catch(console.log('List of devices call failed: ', err));
```

Comment: This makes sense. I will read up on the notation with the arrow you are using. However, I am still confused why chaining the .then immediately vs assigning it to a variable first produced a different result? Did I just luck out?

Comment: No, if you assign it to a variable and call `then` on the variable, it should work just as well. `then` (and `catch`) returns a Promise, after all.